# Must I memorize whether a verb has reflexive meaning or not?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, verbs, memorization

Dictionaries say that for example "open" (without reflexive pronouns) has both meanings (reflexive and not), but "study" (without reflexive pronouns) has **only** reflexive meaning. Is it correct? If it is correct I think the answer will be "YES, I MUST".

Comment: Sorry but where did you see that study has "only a reflexive meaning"? Then, you say the answer is: Yes, I must. Question: answer to what??

Comment: Study can be intransitive or transitive ("I studied" vs "I studied French") but this is nothing to do with reflexive - "I studied myself" is possible but unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

Overall, yes.

Spanish, for example, has a number of reflexive verbs that f rom my understanding are different in meaning from non-reflexive.  For example, *ir* meaning *to go* and *irse* meaning *to leave*.

English has "phrasal verbs" where a preposition acts as a "particle" to modify the meaning of the main verb, and the particle *up* for a few verbs seems to be the most similar to the above.

- For example: *shut* and *shut up* versus Spanish *callar* and *callarse*
- Or, *wash* and *wash up* - if you're going to wash yourself, you'll probably say "I'm going to wash up* instead of *I'm going to wash myself* unless you want to make it clear you're washing yourself and not someone else.

If a verb's object is the same as the subject, 99% of the time, the meaning of the verb doesn't change.

There are the "-self" pronouns, but they are used for emphasis as well as pronouns, so you often hear/see things like "I myself want X ..." or "He wanted to do that himself", etc.

So similarly, regarding *open*, you would say "I'm going to open up to him" (meaning to share more about oneself or other information) versus "I'm going to open myself to him" (and "I'm going to open myself up to him" an emphasized way of saying that).

*Hurt* is weird and a possible exception - *I hurt* means you are experiencing pain in a general sense, and *I hurt myself* means you caused yourself a specific injury.

Comment: Note that in British English _wash up_ means 'wash the dishes after a meal'!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but there are some patterns.  These are called "Labile" or "Ergative" verbs, and their property is that they can be used transitively or intransitivly, and in the intransitive form, the subject plays the same semantic role as the object of the transitive form.

There are many such verbs, but they tend to fall into certain categories.  Wikipedia gives:

- Verbs suggesting a change of state — break, burst, form, heal, melt, tear, transform  [and open]
- Verbs of cooking — bake, boil, cook, fry
- Verbs of movement — move, shake, sweep, turn, walk
- Verbs involving vehicles — drive, fly, reverse, run, sail

By contrast a verb like "study" (which does not suggest a change of state) has a transitive and intransitive form, but the subject of the intransitive form has the same role as the subject of the transitive.

These are not really like the reflexive verbs of French or Spanish. So don't try to use your knowledge of Spanish to guide your understanding of labile verbs in English.

Wikipedia has an [article about Labile or ergative verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labile_verb)
Wiktionary has a [list of Ergative verbs](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_ergative_verbs)